# MIME type not supported

Tags: css, node.js, express

I'm unable to get my stylesheet to apply to my handlebars. Using this exact same code it was able to load yesterday but now I'm getting this MIME error. So I'm not quite sure why this is happening. Any help would be appreciated.

Server Code

```
const sequelize = require('./config/connection');
const SequelizeStore = require('connect-session-sequelize')(session.Store);

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

// Set up Handlebars.js engine with custom helpers
const hbs = exphbs.create({ helpers });


const sess = {
  secret: 'Super secret secret',
  cookie: {},
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  store: new SequelizeStore({
    db: sequelize
  })
};

app.use(session(sess));

// Inform Express.js on which template engine to use
app.engine('handlebars', hbs.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(routes);

sequelize.sync({ force: false }).then(() => {
  app.listen(PORT, () => console.log('Now listening'));
});
```

main.handlebars link reference

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
```

Folder Org

```
server
public
--css
  --style.css
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  My Folder org was NOT in face as I said it was, and when I moved my css folder under public everything worked again.